# Definition: Eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

1) Can a non-square matrix have eigenvalues? Why?

2) True or false: If the characteristic polynomial of a matrix A is p($\lambda$)=$\lambda$^2+1, then A is invertible. 
Thank you!

Comment: Definition: Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a Matrix, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1) No, it has to be a square matrix by definition.

To see why, consider the following:

Recall that for an eigenvector $v$ and and an eigenvalue $\lambda$, you have that $Av$ = $\lambda v$.

Now suppose that dim(v) = n x 1. That means that dim(Av) = n x 1 and dim($\lambda v$) = n x 1. If A is not square then dim(A) must be m x n where $m \neq n$. But then you have that dim($Av$) = (m x n) * (n x1) = m x 1. But we just said that dim(Av) = n x 1 . Thus contradiction.

In regards to your second question, this post answers it completely.
[Is a matrix with characteristic polynomial $t^2 +1$ invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166219/is-a-matrix-with-characteristic-polynomial-t2-1-invertible)

Comment: Thanks! Understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  (1) Try it!  For example, can you solve
$$\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&5&6\cr}\pmatrix{v_1\cr v_2\cr v_3\cr}
  =\lambda\pmatrix{v_1\cr v_2\cr v_3\cr}\ ?$$

(2) You should know

- the connection between whether or not $A$ is invertible and $\det(A)$;
- the connection between $\det(A)$ and the eigenvalues of $A$;
- the connection between the eigenvalues of $A$ and its characteristic polynomial.